# Help on Inequality with Matrix Singular Values

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times d}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times r}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times r}$, where each of $X$ and $Y$ has orthonormal columns and $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq \min{(p, d)}$, prove that $|\langle X, AY \rangle| \leq \sqrt{r\sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i^2(A)}$, where $\sigma_i(A)$ is the $i$th largest singular value of $A$.

I've rewritten $\sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i^2(A)$ as $\Vert A \Vert_F$, and rearranged the expression, although I'm not quite sure what to do, and don't know if I'm even going in the right direction.

Comment: But $AY$ is not consistent since the dimensions don not match.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the dimensions of Y should be $d \times r$

Answer (score 1):

By changing two orthonormal bases, you may assume that $A$ is a singular value matrix. It follows that
$$
|\langle X,AY\rangle|=\sum_{k=1}^r\sigma_i(A)\langle X_{\ast k},Y_{\ast k}\rangle\le\sum_{k=1}^r\sigma_i(A).
$$
Let $s=(\sigma_1(A),\ldots,\sigma_r(A))^T$ and $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^r\sigma_i(A)=\langle s,e\rangle\le\|s\|_2\|e\|_2=\sqrt{r\sum_{i=1}^r\sigma_i^2(A)}.
$$

Comment: Can you explain the first line -- I'm not familiar with the notation $X_{*k}$, and am not quite sure why $\sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_i(A) \langle X_{*k}, Y_{*k} \rangle \leq \sum_{k=1}^r \sigma_i(A)$.

Comment: @py1123 $X_{\ast k}$ is the almost standard notation for the $k$-th column of a matrix $X$. And $\langle u,v\rangle\le1$ for any two unit vectors $u$ and $v$, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.